# Entity Framework - SQL command to LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I can't convert this SQL command to LINQ

```
SELECT tarif.*, prirazeni.Nazev
FROM `tarif`
INNER JOIN prirazeni
ON tarif.intern_id = prirazeni.intern_id
WHERE tarif.id_pojistovna = 'xx' AND cena IS NOT NULL AND prirazeni.nazev = 'yyyy'
GROUP BY id_vstupni_zdroj
```

My LINQ:

```
var total = (from tarif in context.Tarifs
             join prirazeni in context.Prirazenis on tarif.Intern_id equals prirazeni.Intern_id into joined
             from Join in joined
             where tarif.Id_pojistovna == idPojistovna && Join.Nazev == nazev && tarif.Cena != null && tarif.Id_vstupni_zdroj != idVstupniZdroj 
             group tarif by tarif.Id_vstupni_zdroj into tarifGrouped
             from grouped in tarifGrouped
             select grouped
             ).ToList();
```

On MySQL Adminer works SQL commands fine but LINQ returns all rows.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have extra into commands
try this one.

```
var total = (from tarif in context.Tarifs
             join prirazeni in context.Prirazenis on tarif.Intern_id equals prirazeni.Intern_id
             where tarif.Id_pojistovna == idPojistovna && prirazeni.Nazev == nazev && tarif.Cena != null && tarif.Id_vstupni_zdroj != idVstupniZdroj
             group by tarif.Id_vstupni_zdroj
             select new {tarif, prirazeni}).ToList();
```